# How to set lower-bound to type parameters in TypeScript?

Tags: generics, typescript, types, type-bounds

In TypeScript (my version: 2.1.1), it is okay to set an upper-bound to type parameters like this:

```js
class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Kitten extends Cat{}

function foo<A extends Animal>(a: A) { /* */ }
```

How can I set a lower-bound on `A`? The following code does not work:

```js
class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Kitten extends Cat{}

function foo<A super Kitten>(a: A) { /* */ }
```

It will cause a compilation error.

People in the GitHub issue [#13337](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13337) of the TypeScript repo have suggested to use

```js
function foo <X extends Y, Y>(y: Y) { /* */ }
```

to lower-bound `Y` with `X`. But this does not cover my case, in which `X` is an actual type instead of a type parameter.

Any thoughts on how to lower-bound a type parameter?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? If `A super Kitten` then `A` is clearly a `Kitten`, a `Cat` and an `Animal`, how would you benefit from narrowing it down? Can you give a real example of how that will be used?

Comment: Since you used Java-like syntax, I assume you took inspiration for your question from Java's contravariance. Indeed, Java allows contravariance only in wildcards (e.g. `Comparable<? super String>`), not in type parameter declaration contexts (declarations of generic classes, interfaces and/or methods). The reason is, as other people pointed out, that the lower bound would not be meaningful in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Lower-bound for generics is not supported by TypeScript yet. Such suggestion is currently discussed - TypeScript developers are not sure that such feature is necessary. So, we can only wait and hope, that they will agree to implement it.

See the issue in TypeScript issue tracker here - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. The first is practical:

#### Constraint would have no effect

I don't think this is a conceptually meaningful restriction. It sounds like a variant on parameter contravariance. What you're saying is that you're willing to accept any type that is a superclass of `Kitten`.

The problem is that the following also hold true:

- `Kitten` is a subclass of `Cat`.
- `Cat` is a subclass of `Animal`.

So far we're good. But then also consider the following:

- Like any TypeScript `class`, `Animal` is a subclass of `Object` which is the global root type.
- Everything is considered a TypeScript `Object`.

So a restriction where `A` must be superclass of `Kitten` would effectively mean that `A` can only be assumed to be an `Object` which means that the type constraint is meaningless because all types would satisfy that requirement.

#### Violates The Liskov Substitution Principle

The other problem is that this violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#A_typical_violation), which states that any property that holds true for a class `T` should also hold true for its subclasses. So placing a constraint that would accept objects of class `Cat` but not its subclass `Kitten` would violate that rule.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong, because lower bound is used years in Java.

Comment: I think FstTesla’s response in the comments on the question addresses that, is there something I’m missing?

Comment: See the link I provided in my answer to this question. There is much discussion.