# How to type a generic type as a subset of an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible to enforce a generic type (`T` here) to be a subset of an interface ?
Example:

```
interface Type {
  a: () => number
  b: () => string
}

const func = <T /* Some condition */>(): T => { return ... }

func<Type>(); // OK
func<{a: () => number>(); // OK
func<{a: () => number, c: any}>(); // Error !
```

---

**Why do I need this ?**

The case below built an interface with the return types of `Type`. (`TypeReturn` will mean something like `{a: number, b: string}`).

```
type TypeReturn<T> = { [key in keyof T]: (ReturnType<Type[key]>)[] }
```

But typescript complains at `Type[key]` because he can't ensure that `T` will be a key of `Type`.

Comment: Your update to the question invalided my answer using `T extends Partial<Type>`. I wouldn't be surprised if you can't do what you're asking to do, since in general where you have `T` and `U extends T`, you're allowed to use `U` where you can use `T`. I don't understand why you want `{a: () => number, c: any}` to fail. This question seems related, perhaps a duplicate target: [*How to set lower-bound to type parameters in TypeScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657544/how-to-set-lower-bound-to-type-parameters-in-typescript)

Comment: In a comment on my answer you said *"I didn't expect `func<{c: any}>()` to works when `func<{a: () => number, c: any}>();` don't."* The former has nothing in common with `Type`, but the latter does have something in common with `Type`: `{a: () => number}`. If you want your second example (`func<{a: () => number>();`) to work, as I said above, I don't think you'll get `func<{a: () => number, c: any>();` to fail. But I'm not a TypeScript wizard, and it has a **lot** of power, so... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a recursive [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to simulate what you're looking for, since TypeScript doesn't really have [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) which would prohibit extra properties.  Here's how I might do it:

```
type Exactly<T, U> = T & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>;
const func = <T extends Exactly<Partial<Type>, T>>(): T => { return null! }

func<Type>(); // OK
func<{ a: () => number }>(); // OK
func<{ a: () => number, c: any }>(); // Error !
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Types of property 'c' are incompatible.
```

This does what you've stated you want.  Note that `TypeReturn` will still fail to compile, though, because even though `T extends Exactly<Partial<Type>, T>` represents the constraint, the compiler can only reason about concrete values of `T` that way; it doesn't understand the constraint's implications when `T` is still generic.  You'll need to convince the compiler further, such as using the built-in utility type [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) to ensure that `K` will be assignable to `keyof Type`:

```
type TypeReturn<T extends Exactly<Partial<Type>, T>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (ReturnType<Type[Extract<K, keyof Type>]>)[] // okay now
}

type A = TypeReturn<Pick<Type, "a">> // type A = {  a: number[]; }
type B = TypeReturn<Pick<Type, "b">> // type B = {  a: string[]; }
type AB = TypeReturn<Type> // type AB = { a: number[]; b: string [] }
type Oops = TypeReturn<{ a: () => number, c: any }>
//                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Types of property 'c' are incompatible.
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Impressive. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't do this... But you can *partially* do this by conditionally requiring a specific string argument. Unfortunately, this makes the errors really bad, forcing you to provide an argument to see the actual error you want to trigger. [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=17#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOKDeAoZZOALmQAoBKZAXgD5kQBXAWwCNoDlXTKb6BnMFFABzPAF88eACYQEAGzhQUMRiARhgAexDJV6gDypkEAB6QQ0-sgAKSzXHlGsEWrTKdCAOh8IAFnIA1qQA2oEQ6FowaAC6JuYQltZhEVFoLnEA-MghccSehIUhAOTG4ejWSiggWmBEyPyMrPwQdWkY2Mjl-MUxeBSkqFL6CM7Y7hQA3MgA9DPIAPIA0ngjBjhEPFR0DCzsUMjiE9NziytrGyS7bNCHx7PzAKJQUFpQADQMtUT8-MAiIDgrHkKDAWnS2FWalGly2fGu+0+CFIcBA6DulBOTxeb0+ZiEcC6EQKpwAgrolCIWIk6jA3shiv4gsVkAB3ODWGp1TCvABuwFk0i8w2hBhAEF50HcxWKVDJUCpzBpyDSYBcDIARBqWcBOd8OX8AUCQcgwchMEo4ErIFASfNVerihqyhFKsovnVCY1mq0VdEOihutqvGQAEwAZgALABWChSU4ACS0rIl0E+YD8urZOmK3OUkvApoCei08nkydEXjQmesCFRXK4KB5qfAECFeAQOkEyFMNGQl14G2UYEYUF0AEZDkjSPB5C1Dh2u3V0KQ7FAHE4A-RqD2oYY1dg0ugJkA)

```
interface Type {
  a: () => number
  b: () => string
}

declare function func<T extends Partial<Type>>(
    ...check: [keyof T] extends [keyof Type] ? [] :
        ['T keys are not a subset of Type keys']
): T

func<Type>(); // OK
func<{ a: () => number }>(); // OK
func<{ a: number }>(); // Error, not assignable to Type
func<{ a: () => number, c: any }>(); // Error, extra key
    // An argument for 'check' was not provided.

func<never>('') // Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter
    // of type '"T keys are not a subset of Type keys"'.(2345)

// However, this won't prevent the following. This cannot be prevented.
const x = { a() { return 1 }, c: false }
const y: Partial<Type> = x
func<typeof y>()
```