# Conditional types and generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking for some insight / rationale into what the typescript compiler (4.4.2) is doing in this case:

```js
export function T<TVal extends number>(): void
{
    type moo = TVal extends number ? true : false;
    let boo: moo;
    boo = true; // TS2322: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'moo'.
    boo = false; //TS2322: Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'moo'.
    boo;

    type meep = TVal extends number ? { sad: true } : { times: true };
    let hmmm: meep;
    hmmm = { sad: true, times: true }; // TS2322: Type '{ sad: true; times: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'meep'.
    hmmm = { sad: true }; // TS2322: Type '{ sad: true; }' is not assignable to type 'meep'.
    hmmm = { times: true }; // TS2322: Type '{ times: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'meep'.
    hmmm;
}
```

I thought perhaps the conditional was evaluating to a union or perhaps intersection, but it appears to be neither based on the above error messages. I've had a browse of the issues on github but they don't appear to be quite the same.

To be clear I'm not asking how to do something, I'm asking about the why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657544/how-to-set-lower-bound-to-type-parameters-in-typescript)

This is just the lack-of lower-bound inference for a type